# Linux Attach Multiple files Using Mailx

Tags: linux, bash, mailx

I am trying to send multiple attachments but not working using mpack/mailx

example below

```
#!/bin/bash

fileName1="/tst/test.xls"
fileName2="/tst2/test1.csv"
mailBodyFile="/tmp/test.tmp"
MailTo="xyz@test.com"
TodayDate=$(date)


recordCount="`cat ${fileName1} | wc -l`"

mailSubject="Test ${TodayDate}"

if [[ ${recordCount} -gt 1 ]]
then
    
    echo -e "Test,\n\nTest123" > ${mailBodyFile}
    mailx -s "${mailSubject}" -a ${fileName1} ${fileName2} -d ${mailBodyFile} ${MailTo}

else

    echo -e "xyz" > ${mailBodyFile}
fi
```

is there another option to send multiple attachment files?

the script hangs when using mpack (multiple attachments not supported).

Comment: *recordCount="`cat ${fileName1} | wc -l`"* Before we go further, you can't do that with an Excel file. It doesn' t have lines

Comment: You probably have `mutt` too, so use `cat ${mailBodyFile} | mutt -s "${mailSubject}" ${MailTo} -a ${fileName1} ${fileName2} 
`

Comment: Note that `${variable}` doesn't properly quote the variable, and is subject to splitting on whitespace, to often disastrous consequences. Use `"$variable"` to quote.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach multiple files with mailx, you just need to proceed each filename with the -a option. Also, -d puts mailx into "debug" mode, it doesn't allow you to specify a file as the body of the message. You could just "cat" the body of the message to mailx, or use standard redirection. The end results would be something like:

`mailx -s "${mailSubject}" -a "${fileName1}" -a "${fileName2}" -d "${MailTo}" < "${mailBodyFile}"`

Comment: ${mailBodyFile} | mutt -s "${mailSubject}" ${MailTo} -a ${fileName1} ${fileName2}